# Get col-md-6 divs next to each other

Tags: html, css

Since I'm using two col-md-6 divs, shouldn't they be aligned next to each other? I've also set the display to inline-block and have the width of both at 50%.

https://jsfiddle.net/aw406sgm/1/

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.col-md-6 {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class = "wrapper">
  <div class = "container">
    <div class = "row">
      <div class = "col-md-6">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class = "row">
      <div class = "col-md-6">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try resizing the window and you will see that on bigger resolution the two divs will actually be right next to each other.

If you want the divs to be next to each other on all screens, you should use **col-xs-6**

And you shouldn't use row for each div

```css
.col-xs-6 {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
}
.col-xs-6:nth-of-type(even) {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class = "wrapper">
  <div class = "container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Comment: Thanks! I was just following the Bootstrap Grid guideline on w3schools (https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp), but perhaps I misunderstood. I also thought using xs was only for mobile since it also says that on the w3schools guide, so thanks for clarifying that!

Answer (score 0):

No need to add another row for each grid class. Kindly check the updated code.

```html
<div class = "wrapper">
    <div class = "container">
      <div class = "row">
        <div class = "col-md-6">
        </div>
        <div class = "col-md-6">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the two div in the next to each other.Keep the two div inside the row.If u give col-md-6 it will take css from 992px and for col-sm-6 it will take from 768px.

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.col-xs-6 {
  border-right: 2px solid red;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class = "wrapper">
    <div class = "container">
      <div class = "row">
        <div class = "col-xs-6"></div>
        <div class = "col-xs-6"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

The two `col-md-6` elements are children of `row` elements which are block elements. To align the two elements next to each other, you need to use the following. You should also remove the `display:inline-block` and keep the the `float:left;` as inline-block elements include an often unwanted space which would cause your second element to break onto a new line.

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.col-md-6 {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6"></div>
          <div class="col-md-6"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

It's a simple thing, and please don't make the mistake again. Every ROW is divided into COLUMNS (represented by col)

```
<div class = "wrapper">
    <div class = "container">
      <div class = "row">
        <div class = "col-md-6">
        </div>
        <div class = "col-md-6">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

set height = auto;

Comment: Welcome to SO Martin. That's not particularly polite or conducive to a healthy atmosphere. I would recommend that you read this and amend your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice